# mySQL How to alter column to have foreign key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to alter a column in one of my tables to that it references another column in another table. I've tried to introduce a foreign key the following ways:

> ALTER TABLE `table` ALTER COLUMN `id_l` int NOT NULL, foreign key (`id_l`) references table_b(`id_l`);
>
> ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `id_l` `id_l` int NOT NULL, foreign key (`id_l`) references table_b(`id_l`);

I am thrown a syntax error.

A work around is to delete the table and create a new one with the desired reference (this works) but I want to change this table as it is, not to transfer the data. How do I do this?

MySQL Server 5.6.17

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `ALTER TABLE` along with `ADD CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CONSTRAINT fk_l_id FOREIGN KEY (id_l) REFERENCES table_b(id_l);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you already have a foreign key and you want to change it you can do :

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP CONSTRAINT your_constraint;
```

then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (your_column) REFERENCES other_table(other_column);
```

> if you don't know your constraint name you can do `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;`

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with other answers. and after some research I find this answer

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE_NAME`
ADD COLUMN `COLUMN_NAME` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER 
`AFTER_COLUMN_NAME`, 
ADD FOREIGN KEY `FOREIGN_RELATION_NAME`(`COLUMN_NAME`) REFERENCES 
`FOREIGN_TABLE`(`FOREIGN_COLUMN`)  ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```